# Submenu en Java y condicional switch

Tags: java

Tengo un inconveniente con mi código, el problema se me presenta a la hora de salirme de un Submenu para volver al menu principal, lo que sucede es que al yo salirme del Submenu me está ejecuntando el default del switch y no entiendo por que lo hace.

Código del Menu principal:

```
int opcion;
    do {

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccione una opcion. "
                + "\n 1. Crear producto. "
                + "\n 2. Modificar producto. "
                + "\n 3. Salir."));

        switch (opcion) {

            case 1: crearProducto();
                    break;

            case 2: modificarProducto();
                    break;

            case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hasta pronto.", "Hasta pronto", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    break;

            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dato no valido.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    } while (opcion != 3);
```

Código del Submenu:

```
int opcion;
    do {

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Que producto desea modificar. "
                + "\n 1. Productos solidos. "
                + "\n 2. Productos liquidos. "
                + "\n 3. Volver al Menu Principal."));

        switch (opcion) {

            case 1: modificarSolidos();
                    break;

            case 2: modificarLiquido();
                    break;

            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dato no valido.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                     break;
        }

    } while (opcion != 3);
```

PD: AMBOS ESTÁN CREADOS EN MÉTODOS SEPARADO.

Gracias.

Comment: No te enitendo cuando dices de qué depende, me podrías ser más especifico, creo yo no sé si es lo que me preguntas es que cuando ejecuto el programa al entrar a la aprte de Modificar Producto y darle a vovler al Submenu me saca pero me ejecuta el default. Gracias.

Comment: Voté para el cierre de esta pregunta porque: _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te fijas en tu submenu no has tenido en cuenta cuando el usuario introduce el número 3 que en tu submenú sería salir al menú principal.

Es por eso por lo que te está ejecutando la opción `default` antes de salir del bucle ya que los bucles `do-while` primero se ejecutan y después realizan la comparación, es decir, cuando introduzcas el número 3 se ejecutará la opción `default` y después saldrá del bucle.

Comment: Tienes razón, que tonto soy, pero una pregunta no tendría que romperse o salirse del bucle ya que la condición es que si opcion es igual a 3 se detenga, bueno así lo vi yo, pero gracias por tu aporte, me funcione :D

Comment: @CamiloJc Si te fijas la condición en un bucle `do-while` funciona de la siguiente manera. Primero ejecuta el código contenido dentro del bucle y después evalúa la condición, es decir, el código se ejecutará **al menos** una vez. En cambio, si usaras un bucle del tipo `while` primero evalúa la condición y después ejecuta el código por lo que si que saldría del bucle sin ejecutarte la opción por defecto antes de salir del mismo.

Comment: Ouh ya lo entiendo, gracias por tu aclaración, lo tendré siempre en cuenta. Gracias :D